# Java. Метод split()

Tags: java

у меня есть фраза

```
String expected = "Выбирать решения - это легко."
```

Как при помощи метода `split()` разделить ее на массив строк, так чтобы последнее слово "легко." осталось с точкой?

Comment: expected.split(" "); - делите строку по пробелам, в чем проблема то?

Comment: сори ребят, я не обратил внимание на текст с кот я сравнивал, там нет точки после этого слова)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = "Выбирать решения - это легко.";
for (String s : str.split(" ")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```